# How can I use Synergy when connected through different routers?

Tags: networking, synergy

I use [synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/) to control my laptop from my desktop when I have my laptop docked at my workstation.  Currently, I need to keep my laptop wired to the same router that my desktop is connected to in order to use synergy.  However, I will also take my laptop and work from other parts of the house.  I'd like to use just wireless on the laptop, so I don't have to switch connections to get up and move around.

My desktop has a wired connection to a router.  When I'm using wireless on my laptop, I'm connecting through a different router.  Is there a way to set up synergy to connect from the wireless router `192.168.17.*` to the wired network `192.168.250.*`?

I don't know much about network set up or terminology, so if I'm not including any pertinent details, please ask.

Comment: I think this depends on the configurability of the router. Afaik it should work as long as both routers use the same subnet, but of course this f.e. also requires that only one of them is assigning ip adresses. If you then cconfigure the second router to not act as a dhcp server etc but statically (if necessary), f.e. I think in generaly routers do not assing above 200 or so, so using 220 should be safe.
As an alternate solution, could you not just use the wireless router for your desktop as well?

Comment: Is there a reason you have 2 routers? Why not just use the wireless one? Or put the wireless one in access point mode (if it can) so you can be on the same subnet. There are definitely ways to do it across subnets though. Just seems odds.

Comment: @Falmarri: It's a little bit odd, but I have the same configuration for some pretty specific reasons.

Comment: @Falmarri: yes, the wired router connects directly to our company's VPN allowing my VoiIP phone to connect, and my computer to access company resources.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to change your subnets to match or anything fancy like that. You don't need a VPN either. What you do need is to establish traffic between those two end points.

The good news it that most routers have a facility for this. Two as a matter of fact. One is DMZ, the other port forwarding. Both basically amount to the same thing, but DMZ forwards everything instead of just a few ports. The idea is that you don't really need to talk to the ROUTER on ... say ... port 24800. Any traffic that comes to the router on that port can be passed along to a specific computer behind the router as if it was directed for it.

I assume your desktop is setup as the server with the laptop as the client. If this is not the case you'll need to reverse the procedure.

Synergy defaults to running on port 24800. If you changed this, be sure to adjust below.

1. Open up the router that your desktop is connected to and add a port forwarding rule to forward port 24800 to your desktop.
2. Change your laptop synergy config to connect to the desktop's router IP address as it's "server".
3. Viola!

Comment: Yes, my desktop is set up as the server.  Thanks!  (Out of curiosity, would this be possible going the other direction?  IE if my laptop was the server)

Comment: @David: Yes, it would. You just reverse the process. You would seutup the port forwarding on the router that your laptop connects to and change the synergy client on the desktop to talk to that router's IP as it's server.

Comment: How to setup port forwarding rule on a laptop connected to wireless? Which command to use?

Answer (score -2):

As long as the two machines can see each other, Synergy will work fine. From the command line, ping one machine from the other to test their connectivity (eg, on the laptop, type ifconfig (*nix)/ipconfig (win), find the ip address, and from the other, type ping  from the command line). This will probably not work the first time. At that point, you will need to configure your routers correctly- how to do this will depend on the specific routers. I would choose one to be the primary router for your setup, and let the other just be a fancy switch. If you have a cable/dsl modem, use the router closest to that to be the primary (in some cases, one of those two may be the modem itself).

Comment: Given two `192.x` subnets, the two will not be able to talk to eachother. The OP clearly knows that this would work in the same subnets but is asking for a solution ACROSS routers, not dropping one router from the network.